# pip will not install module in venv

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

When I run `pip install django-pgjsonb` as a regular user it fails with `setuptools must be installed to install from a source distribution`.

But setuptools is installed as can be seen from the fact that `pip list` includes the following packages:

```
Django (1.8.4)
pip (7.1.2)
setuptools (18.3.2)
wheel (0.24.0
```

Any ideas what the error is?

**UPDATE** I cannot reproduce the problem in a fresh venv.  So I'm just recreating a venv with the same stuff.

However I'm leaving the question open in case anyone has anything to fix.

Comment: Are you sure you're running `pip` in the venv?  Did you source the venv's `activate.sh` script?  Can you show us a complete sequence of commands -- starting with creating the venv -- that will reproduce the problem?

Comment: I am sure that I'm running `pip` in the venv.  I checked with `which pip`.  I did source the environment.  I just tried setting up a second venv and could not reproduce the problem.  Then sourced the original one and it happened again.

Therefore I somehow wound up with a corrupted venv.  But I have no clue how.  However I can work around it very easily by recreating the venv.  So I'm doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have activated a virtual environment try the following. It worked for me.

```
pip install --user -Iv django-pgjsonb
```